# Banach-Tarski Paradox Confusion

Tags: measure-theory

I recently read the [Wikipedia article on the Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#A_sketch_of_the_proof) and while reading it seemed odd to me the sketch of the proof.

I could be wrong but in the proof a valid element of the group $F_2$ would be $aba^{-1}$. When rotating by $\theta$ along the 2 axes wouldn't this element be the same as $b$ since you rotate by $\theta$ on the x-axis rotate by $\theta$ on the y-axis and the rotate back by $\theta$ on the x-axis? Isn't $ab$ the same as $ba$? So wouldn't the subsets $S(a)$, $S(b)$, $S(a^{-1})$ and $S(b^{-1})$ by themselves already contain all of $F_2$ since you can simply extend the expression from there to go even further into $S(b)$ and you can easily do the same to get the other "starting points"?

Anyone mind clearing me up? Am I getting something wrong or not? Does it even matter?

Edit: Ok thanks to Ross Millikan for clearing this up. I thought rotations would commute. Read his answer for a good clarification that shows that they don't.

Comment: Neither $F_2$ nor $SO(3)$ is abelian.

Comment: As mentioned above, by anomaly, $F_2$ is not abelian.  In case the terminology is unfamiliar to you, that means in particular that you can not simply rearrange things being multiplied.  $aba^{-1}\neq b$ and $ab\neq ba$.  These are distinctly different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that rotations in different axes do not commute, so $aba^{-1} \neq b$. This is what is needed to get a free group.  I suggest you try it yourself with a six sided die.  Put it on the table with $1$ facing you and $2$ to the left.  $4$ will be up.  Let $a$ be a quarter turn clockwise around a vertical axis and $b$ a quarter turn moving the front face to the top.  $aba^{-1}$ (we apply the rightmost first) brings $2$ to the front, then $3$, then $1$ and $2$ ends on top.  $b$ along puts $1$ on top and $3$ on the front.  To make the proof work we need to find a pair of rotations so that no sequence of them results in the identity, so these quarter turns do not work for Banach-Tarski, but they show rotations do not commute.